# Make mistakenly thinks rule succeeded because of 0-sized file generated by output redirect

Tags: shell, io-redirection, make

In a makefile, I have several rules that look like this:

```
out.txt: foo.sh input.txt
  ./foo.sh -i input.txt > out.txt
```

If `foo.sh` fails, then `out.txt` will be created as a 0-sized file. If I run *make* again, it will mistakenly assume that the `out.txt` file was created successfully, and it won't run the rule again.

What's the right way to handle this sort of scenario?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can request that make delete the target file if the rule fails, by defining a [special target](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Special-Targets.html) named [`.DELETE_ON_ERROR`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Special-Targets.html#index-g_t_002eDELETE_005fON_005fERROR-232). It doesn't need to do anything or have any dependencies, so just add this to your makefile:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

Then you get the following:

```
$ cat Makefile
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
foo:
    false > foo

$ make
false > foo
make: *** [foo] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `foo'
zsh: exit 2     make

$ stat foo
stat: cannot stat `foo': No such file or directory
```

---

From [Errors in Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Errors.html#Errors):

> Usually when a recipe line fails, if it has changed the target file at all, the file is corrupted and cannot be used—or at least it is not completely updated. Yet the file's time stamp says that it is now up to date, so the next time `make` runs, it will not try to update that file. The situation is just the same as when the shell is killed by a signal; see [Interrupts](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Interrupts.html#Interrupts). So generally the right thing to do is to delete the target file if the recipe fails after beginning to change the file. `make` will do this if `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` appears as a target. This is almost always what you want `make` to do, but it is not historical practice; so for compatibility, you must explicitly request it.

Comment: The advantage of `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` is that it automatically applies to every rule. It has downsides though: it's specific to GNU make; it doesn't trigger if the build is interrupted violently (power failure, unmaskable signal); it removes the partial file, which can be useful in investigating failed builds.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever possible, makefile rules should first create their target under a temporary name, then move it into place. That way, if the build process is interrupted for any reason, there won't be a half-written target file that can't be distinguished from a fully written file.

```
out.txt: foo.sh input.txt
        ./foo.sh -i input.txt >$@.tmp
        mv -f $@.tmp $@
```

`mv -f $@.tmp $@` is a common makefile idiom.

[Juliano's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/make-mistakenly-thinks-rule-succeeded-because-of-0-sized-file-generated-by-output/16178#16178) shows a variant where the name of the temporary file is generated dynamically. The dynamic name generation is required if there may be more than one process generating the same target or if the directory can be written to by other users. This is very rarely the case for a build tree (if these were issues, a lot of what's going on in a typical makefile would break), so the extra complexity is usually not necessary.

Comment: Is that actually necessary? I thought make would clean up half-written files if it got interrupted or the process has a signal (and experimentation seems to indicate it does). By default it doesn't clean up files if the process exits non-zero, but that's what `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` is in my answer; with that on there should be no need for this temp file juggling

Comment: @Michael What if `make` dies without having time to clean up (power failure, OOM, user sending a `KILL` signal, …)?

Comment: Well, how often does that happen? If you're `kill -9`ing `make` you deserve what you get, and I would hope somebody is going to do a clean build if there's something exceptional like a power failure

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that `foo.sh` is something you have written (or is generated by something you wrote), I would consider adding a `-o` flag to it, which takes the output file name. Then you do not have to depend on the default I/O redirection behavior. Your script can clean up partial output files, or possibly even avoid creating the file in the first place if you can detect the error early enough.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `foo.sh` properly returns non-zero on error. Then you should make a temporary, and only overwrite the output on success.

```
tmp=$$(mktemp) && ./foo.sh input.txt > $$tmp && mv $$tmp $@ || rm -f $$tmp && false
```

Comment: I wouldn't delete `$tmp` if the generation fails, partial files can be useful to debug failed builds. If you do, you must make sure the command fails if `rm` is invoked, e.g. `|| rm $$tmp && false`.

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to keep partial files around for debugging, but that would complicate the solution a little. I added the bit about false, good.